# C# Problems with Task.Delay() function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a program which needs to play music on specified times.

```
private void SetUpTimer(string alertTime, string sound, int duration)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Made it"); //For Testing

            var time = alertTime;
            var timeParts = time.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

            var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
            var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day,
                       int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));
            TimeSpan t;
            if (date > dateNow)
                t = date - dateNow;
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            Task.Delay(t).ContinueWith((x) => Bell(sound, duration));

            MessageBox.Show("Done"); //For Testing

        }
```

It literally does nothing! I ran it and it showed "Made it" and right after pressing OK it showed "Done". So It doesn't wait for specified time, neither does it run the Bell Method.

Any idea what is causing this???

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Trying it out now!

Comment: " neither does it run the Bell Method" that's does not sound true... Are you absolutely sure you put breakpoint into that method and it is not called after `t` milliseconds passes?

Comment: forget tasks since this isn't a task method. Try Thread.Sleep() instead. Tasks are not always the answer.

Comment: Which value contains in `t` variable? Could you pass `t.ToString()` to the last `MessageBox.Show` to view it value?

Comment: @hal just tought about the same thing, on it

Comment: @NathanA nice trolling :) Freezing WinForm app is definitely entertaining suggestion...

Comment: GUYS! Ummm, I have just discovered that it always executes

Comment: else{ return; }

Comment: @CodingWithAdin, so, why you wrote `after pressing OK it showed "Done"` ? Where is truth?) If `else {return;}` is executed, you sould not see  `MessageBox.Show("Done")`

Comment: Oh wait. I tought another MessageBox with information on the time is "Done!"

Comment: If you get to the `return`, you're using the wrong time. If you get the second message box, you just need to wait for the `Bell` method to execute (this has no relation to the "Done" message box). If it doesn't happen at the correct time, you might be getting exceptions in the `Bell` method, so make sure to put a breakpoint there or better, handle exceptions on the task continuation.

Comment: No, The second one is in the else statement with return

Comment: Solved almost everything, but I would like to freeze everything until it is the specified time

Comment: Done that too. Thx guys

Comment: In face it was not clear, the whole point of tasks is that *stuff keeps happening in the user interface while the task is in flight*. You should expect a delay to "do nothing". If you wrote yourself a to-do list that said "turn on the stereo in five minutes; while you're waiting, make some toast", then the first step *appears* to execute instantly because you can still do stuff *while you are waiting*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Delay` wont do anything on its own. It returns a Task, and if you want to wait for the task to be completed, you need to `await` it. In your case, your code might look something like this:

```
private async Task SetUpTimer(string alertTime, string sound, int duration)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Made it"); //For Testing

        var time = alertTime;
        var timeParts = time.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

        var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day,
                   int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));
        TimeSpan t;
        if (date > dateNow)
            t = date - dateNow;
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        await Task.Delay(t);
        Bell(sound, duration)

        MessageBox.Show("Done"); //For Testing

    }
```

The line beginning with `await` will cause control to return to the calling function, and your task will be scheduled to run on a threadpool thread.

Comment: Trying it out now

Comment: " It returns a Task that you *need to await*" - that's absolutely false. Code would call `Bell` method with or without `await` just fine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If you want the bell to ring before the messagebox shows, you probably would.

Comment: @JAD one usually should use either `await` *or* `.ContinueWith` - since OP started with `.ContinueWith` the fix would be to move message box after `Bell`: `Task.Delay(t).ContinueWith((x) => {Bell(sound, duration);MessageBox.Show("Done");} );` rather than claiming that `await` is required... I'm not sure why this answer suggests mixing two...

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:

Calling `Task.Delay` without an `await` will run that `Task` (in the background) and continue code execution immediately.

If you want to 'wait', you'll need to either `await` the `Task` return from `Task.Delay`, or explicitly wait.

**Solution (with await):**

Note, this will require a signature change of your method, so consumers will need to be updated as well.

```
private async Task Solution1(string alertTime, string sound, int duration)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting...");

    await Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

**Solution (with explicit Wait):**

```
  private void Solution2(string alertTime, string sound, int duration)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Starting...");

      Task.Delay(2000).Wait();

      // add ContinueWith code here

      Console.WriteLine("Done");
  }
```